# How do I pass a variable inside an ".each" function?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I have the following:

```
var columns = ['Fruit', 'Color']

var graphData = [
  [6,3,3,2,5],
  [18,7,6,1,0] 
];

var data = [
    [6,3],
    ['Apple', 'Red']
]
var maxes = [10, 20];

// create table
var table = d3.select("#table").append("table");
var thead = table.append("thead").append("tr");
thead.selectAll("th").data(columns).enter().append("th").text(function(d) {
        return d;
});
var tbody = table.append("tbody");
var trows = tbody.selectAll("tr").data(data).enter().append("tr");
var tcells = trows.selectAll("td").data(function(d, i) { return d; })
    .enter().append("td").text(function(d, i) { return d; });
// update (add a column with graphs)
thead.append("th").text('Graphs');
trows.selectAll("td.graph").data(function(d,i) {return [graphData[i]];})
     .enter().append("td").attr("class", "graph").each(function(test, j){
            var width = 100, height = 20; 
            var x = d3.scale.linear()
                .range([0, width - 10])
                .domain([0,5]);
            var y = d3.scale.linear()
                .range([height, 0])
                .domain([0,maxes[j]);
            var line = d3.svg.line()
                    .x(function(d,i) {return x(i)})
                    .y(function(d) {return y(d)});

            d3.select(this).append('svg')
                    .attr('width', width)
                    .attr('height', height)
                 .append('path')
                    .attr('class','line')
                    .datum(test)
                    .attr('d', line);

});
```

The important part is:

```
 var y = d3.scale.linear()
           .range([height, 0])
           .domain([0,maxes[j]);
```

I am trying to dynamically set the domain of the y axis for each chart. If I get rid of "maxes[j]" and set it manually it works but I'd like to have each chart look correct. As I have it now the jsfiddle doesn't render:

[My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lgq6ct9f/15/)

Comment: use Function.prototype.bind if you use new browsers, or polyfill for old browsers, read on mdn about this.

Comment: `.domain([0,maxes[j]]);` you were missing a `]` on this line - [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lgq6ct9f/16/)

Comment: @smerny If that was the solution I would close this as being a simple typographical error.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek, well that is the reason nothing is rendering. Not sure if OP is going for more than that though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing around pre-determined maxes, you could just use:

```
.domain(d3.extent(test));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `maxes[j]` is always `0`. Change the line:

```
trows.selectAll("td.graph").data(function(d,i) {return [graphData[i]];})
```

to:

```
trows.selectAll("td.graph").data(function(d,i) {return [graphData[i], i];})
```

Note the missing "`, i`".

The final [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lgq6ct9f/17/).